# How to get color from SKSpriteNode?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sprite, sprite-kit

I would like to find how to get the color of the button created with SKNode?
This is how I make my SKNode.

```
SKNode *noddd = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0] size:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];
```

I would like to get the result (getting red, green and blue values) into a simple NSLog.

How to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have the color of a SKSpriteNode by doing this.

```
NSLog(@"%@",sprite.color);
```

But in your case i think it's better to create a button with SKSpriteNode and add it to a Node layer for example layerButtonNode.

Your first create your Button

```
SKSpriteNode *newButton = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0] size:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];
newButton.name=@"buttonName";
```

Add it to the SKNode layer

```
[layerButtonNode addChild: newButton];
```

And then find the SKSpriteNode in this layer by using

```
[self.layerButtonNode childNodeWithName:@"buttonName"].color ;
```

in NSLog like this

```
NSLog(@"%@",[self.layerButtonNode childNodeWithName:@"buttonName"].color);
```